# ajax GET - result from php not passing through

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

i am pulling my hair for days now. Basically, i am using ajax to execute some mysql (PDO) queries:

AJAX

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'update_query.php',
    data: $('#new_form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {alert(data);}
    });
```

update_query.php

```
<?php
require("connection.php"); //contains pwd
try {
    $connection = new PDO( $dns, $utilisateur, $motDePasse);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE XXX");
    $stmt->execute();
    echo json_encode('SUCCESS');
    $connection = null;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode('ERROR:' . $e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
?>
```

The php query works as i can see the result in my DB. However, alert(data) from AJAX does not work. data is empty.

i really can't figure out why. Can i have your views/advices?

Thanks

Comment: Youre code works on me . What do you mean is that the alert(data) alert empty ?

Comment: What is the use of serializing and submitting your form when you did not use it in php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.ajax expects a JSON response, but you used json_encode that will print "success" in output as "text/html" not your desired "application/json".

You must use `header` function to have an "application/json" response:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```